# pandas series containing bytes or string data to json or dictionary type

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas series with `bytes` datatype that I'd like to transform for manipulation and parsing contents.

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0],
                   'bdata': ["b'{\"status\":\"SuccessWithResult\",\"total\":13}"]
                 })

type(df['bdata'][0])

bytes

# Transform to dict
df_zillow_az_v2['attom'] = df_zillow_az_v2['attom'].apply(literal_eval)

ValueError: malformed node or string: b'
```

How do I convert pandas series of type `bytes` to either `json` or `dict` type?

- The data may appear as `str` but it is actually stored as `bytes` in pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

The values of `bdata` column are not `bytes`, they are strings as `type(df['bdata'][0])` tells you. The `b'` is misleading. So you have to remove the characters `b'` from the string before applying `literal_eval`. You can do it using `Series.str.strip`

```
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0],
                   'bdata': ["b'{\"status\":\"SuccessWithResult\",\"total\":13}"]
                 })

df['bdata'] = df['bdata'].str.strip("b'").apply(literal_eval)
```

Output:

```
>>> df['bdata']

0    {'status': 'SuccessWithResult', 'total': 13}
Name: bdata, dtype: object

>>> df['bdata'].apply(type)

0    <class 'dict'>
Name: bdata, dtype: object
```